# How to add an item from db to a list when i click on a link?

Tags: javascript, angular, mongodb, typescript

Here is the interfaces :

```
  export interface Doctor {
  lastName: string;
  firstName: string;
  format: string;
  inami: string;
  _id: string;
  brusafe: {
   login: string;
  };
  }



  export interface DoctorList {
  doctors: Array <{
  id: string;
  gp: boolean;
   }>;
  }
```

Here is my function :

```
addNewDoctor(newDoctor: Doctor) {
console.log(newDoctor);
this.linkedDoctorShort.push({
  id: newDoctor._id,
  gp: false,
});
this.doctorLinked.push(newDoctor);
this.onSave();
}
```

Here is the HTML :

```
<div class="doctorlist">
<a (click)="addNewDoctor(newDoctor)">add</a>
<ul *ngFor="let doctor of doctorLinked; let d = index" >

<li> {{doctor.lastName}} {{linkedDoctorShort[d].gp}}<a 
(click)="setAsGP(ind,isGP)"><i class="material-icons">
    assignment_ind
    </i></a><a (click)="deleteDoctor(doctor.lastName)"> <i 
    class="material-icons">
    delete
    </i></a></li>
   </ul>
</div>
```

I'm trying to add a doctor in a list when click on the link 'add' but its says "Cannot read property '_id' of undefined"

Comment: in `addNewDoctor(newDoctor)` in template, what is `newDoctor`? Seems to be `undefined` to me and that is causing the error...?

Comment: NewDoctor is  the element that is supposed to get all the property from the doctor and display it as an object into the list

Comment: `element that is supposed to get all the property`... what element? Please provide a [mcve]

Comment: im Sorry if  I am misunderstood, i'm not fluent in english, i mean that newDoctor is the parameter of the interface Doctor in my function AddNewDoctor, so i can do like "newDoctor.lastName'  to get the last name from the doctor in my function..

Comment: but where does `newDoctor` come from? Is there any values? I mean, `newDoctor` must come from somewhere, right? In your code you have just `newDoctor` added as a parameter, but nowhere do we see where it's coming from and what the values are of that?

Comment: in the beginning of my code its "public newDoctor : Doctor;" but its still undefined i don't know why

Comment: Well, it's undefined. you are not setting any properties or values to `newDoctor`, so how do you think there would magically be properties and/or values ;)